# Error in creation of custom view

Tags: android, custom-view

i have customview, i want to add that in the xml file i tried like this but i am getting this error

```
  Custom view TouchImageView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors;
  XML attributes will not work
```

this is the xml i am using..

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <view 
   class="com.zoom.TouchImageView"
   android:id="@+id/webView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: pleas clarify your question..

Comment: @AwaisTariq i am getting in the xml graphical layout..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the constructor:

```
public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
{
    super(context, attributeSet);

    //TODO:
}
```

to your custom View class.