# Button on top of a Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying to put a Button on top of a View, which I'm using with a Canvas, but there is no way it work it out.

Any ideas please? I've look everywhere (this seems to be a commom issue) but didn't find any solution.

Thanks,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private RandomShapeView mDrawingArea;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mDrawingArea = (RandomShapeView) findViewById(R.id.drawing_area);
    mDrawingArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

}

}
```

View Class

```
public class RandomShapeView extends View {

Paint paint;

public RandomShapeView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

}

}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    class="com.examples.danilofernandes.canvasonrelativelayout.RandomShapeView"
    android:id="@+id/drawing_area"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z-order is implied in the order the elements appear in the XML. Switch the places, you should be fine.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <com.examples.danilofernandes.canvasonrelativelayout.RandomShapeView
        android:id="@+id/drawing_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It gives me an error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to com.examples.danilofernandes.canvasonrelativelayout.RandomShapeView

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just one thing was missing, which is exactly the issue reported here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352249/error-in-creation-of-custom-view